# Include external excel sheet data in local copy

Tags: excel

Our group tracks activities in a "group-wide" excel sheet. I would like to add my own information to that sheet in my local copy, such that the group data is always up to date, but my own data will only be in my local version. Is this somehow possible?

Simple example:
Cell A1 has data "Group work: Do Test 1"
Cell B1 has (my own data): "Remember to write report about test 1 by 01. July".

Cell B1 is not visible to the others, and if A1 changes, it will be reflected in my version as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can open your file and the group file and then copy the data in the group file to your file (by reference) and like that the group's data in your file will be always update.
for example:
here is book2 - the group's file:

[image]

then you open a new file book1 and put the values from book2 like that:
[image]

now if you will change the "a" in book2 the "a" in book 1 will be changed too.